# Software & Updates (Problem) - Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, updates, software-center

Ever since i upgraded from **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS** to **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS**
the Updater have been a big questien mark.

By default it was set to: **Automatically check for updates** | **Daily**, so far good.
However when i go to: **Ubuntu Software** Center | **Updates**
It says there are new updates. For example: **Web Browser** | **ImageMagic** | **Ubuntu Security** just to mention **3**.

Then when i click on the **Install** button it sometimes shows the installation progress in orange colour, great. But when the install has finnished the **Install** button pops back up again just like it wasn't installed at all and the same Update appears in the list like nothing has been done.

But then if i do continue and install some of the other updates aswell
and do like **3** out of **5** updates a blank page shows up and says it was updated.

*I now have three questiens:*

- Why aren't these updated automatically like all the others?
- Why doesn't the update dissapear from the list after installation finnished?
- Where did the other two updates go that i didn't install?

So, this is the result after running the:
**sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade**
Command in terminal.

PC & Terminal have been on the whole night and it still says **58%**

```
Hit:1 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease             
Hit:3 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease           
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]     
Fetched 102 kB in 0s (139 kB/s)                             
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
4 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libsnapd-glib1 snapd-login-service
Progress: [ 58%] [##################################........................] 
  gnome-software gnome-software-common im-config ubuntu-software
4 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 2 566 kB of archives.
After this operation, 209 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 ubuntu-software amd64 3.20.1+git20161013.0.d77d6cf-0ubuntu2~xenial1 [11,6 kB]
Get:2 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 gnome-software amd64 3.20.1+git20161013.0.d77d6cf-0ubuntu2~xenial1 [227 kB]
Get:3 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 gnome-software-common all 3.20.1+git20161013.0.d77d6cf-0ubuntu2~xenial1 [2 257 kB]
Get:4 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libsnapd-glib1 amd64 1.2-0ubuntu1.1~xenial [35,5 kB]
Get:5 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 im-config all 0.29-1ubuntu12.3 [23,2 kB]
Get:6 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 snapd-login-service amd64 1.2-0ubuntu1.1~xenial [11,1 kB]
Fetched 2 566 kB in 0s (5 475 kB/s)            
(Reading database ... 244570 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../ubuntu-software_3.20.1+git20161013.0.d77d6cf-0ubuntu2~xenial1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking ubuntu-software (3.20.1+git20161013.0.d77d6cf-0ubuntu2~xenial1) over (3.20.1+git20160923.2.7374bdc-0ubuntu1~xenial1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../gnome-software_3.20.1+git20161013.0.d77d6cf-0ubuntu2~xenial1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gnome-software (3.20.1+git20161013.0.d77d6cf-0ubuntu2~xenial1) over (3.20.1+git20160923.2.7374bdc-0ubuntu1~xenial1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../gnome-software-common_3.20.1+git20161013.0.d77d6cf-0ubuntu2~xenial1_all.deb ...
Unpacking gnome-software-common (3.20.1+git20161013.0.d77d6cf-0ubuntu2~xenial1) over (3.20.1+git20160923.2.7374bdc-0ubuntu1~xenial1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libsnapd-glib1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libsnapd-glib1_1.2-0ubuntu1.1~xenial_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libsnapd-glib1:amd64 (1.2-0ubuntu1.1~xenial) ...
Preparing to unpack .../im-config_0.29-1ubuntu12.3_all.deb ...
Unpacking im-config (0.29-1ubuntu12.3) over (0.29-1ubuntu12.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package snapd-login-service.
Preparing to unpack .../snapd-login-service_1.2-0ubuntu1.1~xenial_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking snapd-login-service (1.2-0ubuntu1.1~xenial) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160824-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.48.1-1~ubuntu16.04.1) ........] 
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu4) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.10.6-1ubuntu3.1) ...
Setting up gnome-software-common (3.20.1+git20161013.0.d77d6cf-0ubuntu2~xenial1) ...
Setting up libsnapd-glib1:amd64 (1.2-0ubuntu1.1~xenial) ...
Setting up gnome-software (3.20.1+git20161013.0.d77d6cf-0ubuntu2~xenial1) ...
Setting up ubuntu-software (3.20.1+git20161013.0.d77d6cf-0ubuntu2~xenial1) ...
Setting up im-config (0.29-1ubuntu12.3) ...
Setting up snapd-login-service (1.2-0ubuntu1.1~xenial) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu4) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.10.6-1ubuntu3.1) ...
```

Comment: Please run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` from a terminal to get a better view of what is going on; and edit your question to add the results.

Comment: HI fkraiem! Sure but how do i edit? Can't find any edit button.

Comment: Nevermind found it. Was to light for me eyes to see :) But i don't know how to put the commandline in a list like some other users do it so it will all be in plaintext here.